# How do manually configure a JAXBContext?

Tags: spring-boot, jaxb, jersey, moxy

There's a lot of examples out there explaining how to turn annotated POJO's (alternatively wrapping your non-annotated POJO's in JAXBElement) into XML with Spring and Jersey. This is all good, but it's also a bit mystical to me how it all happens.

I'd like to learn more about how this, and I'd like to provide Jersey with a JAXB implementation of my own choice. I'd like to use [MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/moxy/runtime001.htm) for this.

1. Do I need to "manually" create a ([MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/moxy/runtime002.htm)) [JAXBContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html) for Jersey to use, and somehow provide Jersey with that `JAXBContext`. Will I have to do that through a [JAXBContextFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContextFactory.html)?
2. If the above assumption is correct, how do I provide Jersey with that `JAXBContext`? I've attempted to set up `@Provider` for `ContextResolver<JAXBContext>`, but that didn't really work / make a difference. How do I tell Jersey which JAXBContext to use?

**Spring Configuration**

```
@Provider
public class JAXBConfiguration implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

    private JAXBContext context;

    public JAXBConfiguration() throws Exception {
        this.context = JAXBContext.newInstance("package.where.model.lives");
    }

    @Override
    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        return context;
    }
}
```

**Jersey Resource**

```
@Component
@Path("/test")
public class LabelsResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response getLabels(@QueryParam("labelIds") String labelIds) {

        try {
            DefaultLabel entity = new DefaultLabel();
            entity.setName("name");
            entity.setCode("code");

            // Works    
            //return Response.ok(new JAXBElement<DefaultLabel>(new QName("label"), DefaultLabel.class, entity)).build();

            // Does not work
            return Response.ok(entity).build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.serverError().entity(e.getMessage()).build();
        }

    }
```

Comment: The `ContextResolver` is the correct way to provide your own `JAXBContext`. Are you sure your `JAXBConfiguration`  is being registered?

Comment: Yes @PaulSamsotha, the constructor of the JAXBConfiguration is being invoked - but getContext() of that class is never being invoked. But that may not guarantee that the ContextResolver gets registered...

Comment: @PaulSamsotha it apparently works when i write my own `JAXBEntityProvider` which implements both `MessageBodyWriter` and `MessageBodyReader`, and annotate that `JAXBEntityProvider` with `@Provider`.

Comment: When I tested it, the getContext() was called. I'm not sure what you're doing differently.